# Sel IDE using IE stand alone server it gets stuck on IE page with this message "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to this so forgive me if I don't properly state things. I started learning Selenium using the IDE record tool for Mozilla.  It says you can play back the script in IE by setting up the stand alone server. That worked fine but when I play back, I get the message stated in the title along with a pop up with this very long message.  Below is the message.

Every line in the script opens up a new browser window with the same message.  Very frustrating. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Received command response (!=OK/ERROR): <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"version":"3.0.1","type":"Standalone","consoleLink":"/wd/hub"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>

 Request Data: cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*webdriver&2=http%3A%2F%2Ftemplate.ppgtest.local%2FPortal%2FLogin&3=&4=webdriver.remote.sessionid%3D7d276ca5-a3c2-4527-b535-2e38958624ae
```